# For loop issue, Movie theatre booking system Java

Tags: java, loops, input, logic

I have a question regarding a project I received, it is a standard ticket booking system for a movie theatre. There needs to be a limit of 50 seats in each movie. I need to be able to take the amounts of tickets bought stored so if I bought one ticket, it would register there's now 49 seats available instead of 50. I figured a count-controlled loop would do the trick but when I take the information from what people input in my program it runs all 50 iterations and does not take the input into consideration. I tried to format the program using an if ( x <=50) then run but else if (x > 50) do the next part of my code... I ran into the issue that negative numbers were being used and the amount was not being stored. I have been stuck here for a bit I am not sure what kind of loop to use or how to make sure what is being input is displayed. This is the code for only one of my movie options but I need help with formatting the loop so it runs properly instead of opening 50 of the newFrame1 when I enter a value.

```
static class Seating1 implements ActionListener {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    JFrame newFrame1 = new JFrame("Seating");
    newFrame1.setSize(500, 500);
    JLabel prompt1 = new JLabel("Enter how many tickets you would like");
    JPanel newPanel1 = new JPanel();
    newFrame1.add(newPanel1);

    int x;
    x = Integer.parseInt((JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "enter amount of tickets")));

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int count = 0;
    for (x = 1; x <= 50; x++) {
      JFrame newNewFrame = new JFrame("Approved");
      JLabel amnt =
          new JLabel(
              "You have selected "
                  + x
                  + " seat(s)"
                  + " Those seats are available, your order is processed ");
      newNewFrame.add(amnt);

      amnt.setVisible(true);
      newNewFrame.setVisible(true);
      newNewFrame.setSize(500, 500);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Whatever value you get from the optionpane for the # of tickets, you throw it away and assign one to `x` with the first part of the `for` loop.

Comment: Thank you, I am wondering what to do instead

Comment: I changed the for loop to  

for (x=x; x<=50; x++); 

and it still runs where it starts at what is entered but the frame opens up whatever number is entered 50 -x times after that

Comment: `for (int i = x; i < x+50; i++) {`

Comment: @bacteriophage ok...you mean to say that ..if i have 50 seats and a customer books some number of seats ...then that those number of seats should be stored and for the next customer the seats of the 1st customer should not be available , am i right ?